# Empty string response curl php on https posting

Tags: php, curl

Posting on HTTPS API receives empty response. Before when using HTTP everything worked fine. But last week when 3rd party company changed the link to HTTPS everything has changed. I didn't receive the actual message I receives using HTTP. I made some research about it and I find out that php curl doesn't able to read the secured connection??? I asked the 3rd party company to provide the certificate they have in HTTPS so that I can include it on my working source code (Below) and test if I can receive any response, but I failed!!!! Here's my source code below. can someone help me about it? thanks

**UPDATE** Include the header

```
$headers = array(
// "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
"Content-Type: text/xml;charset=\"UTF-8\"",
"SOAPAction: \"http://tempuri.org/IAppMain/Post\"",
"Connection: Keep-Alive",
"Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
 ); 


$soap_do = curl_init();
set_time_limit(0);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            $url);  
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,    true); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,      10);   
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CAINFO, APPPATH . "/RSA/BC/sslcertificateof.pem");
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true ); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $xml_post_string); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,        TRUE); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $headers);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HEADER,         false);

// Converting
$response = curl_exec($soap_do); 
$error    = curl_error($soap_do);

if(curl_errno($soap_do))
{
    echo "Curl Failed: " . curl_errno($soap_do), "<br/>";
    echo curl_error($soap_do); 
} else {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($response);   // Suppose if there's no error I will see an XML, but I get empty string.
}
```

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: no output on response

Comment: So it just says "Hey" and no errors?  If you're trying to post XML, you need to set an appropriate Content-Type header in the request to text/xml.

Comment: @drew010 please see the update above

Comment: Where does `$response` come from?  I don't see `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` but you also left out the curl_exec call from your code.

Comment: @drew010 please see the update again, now i hope u had the solution. may i know please?

Comment: What does `var_dump($response);` return?

Comment: empty string "", or false

Comment: @drew010 you have an updates?

Comment: Not really. There's still not enough information to go off of.  You have CURLOPT_VERBOSE, are you getting anything useful from the debug output?

Answer (score 0):

You can try add it to `php.ini`

```
curl.cainfo=c:\path\to\cacert.pem
```

And setup `curl_setopt_array`

```
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false     // Disabled SSL Cert checks
);
curl_setopt_array( $soap_do, $options );
```

Give me your result in comment.

Comment: Hi Just wonder if this will work on cpanel? I'm not using localhost for this.

Comment: Yes. It's will work with almost case about ssl curl. Are you try this?

Comment: I will inform the hosting provider about this. In meantime is there any other way (Hard way) to accomplish this?

Comment: You can try add curl_setopt_array like me. Are you do it yet?

Comment: Hi, I update my curl source code but still I didn't get an XML response. please see source code above.

Comment: @PHP4lite What's your full url?

Comment: you can only browse those page when your ip is whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to 0
And at the same time try initially setting CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to FALSE, so you can be 100% sure that you what part of the connect-process you are debugging.
And finaly: use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to monitor the traffic